# Sorting data from one column

Tags: vba

I'm trying to build a basic macro that will sort my data:

```
Sub Makro1()

Range("N1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("N2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("D2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("N3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

My data is N columns and one record takes 3 cells that I would like to copy to one row as above.

Now I would like the VBA to keep copying until data in column N ends.

So N4 to A3, N5 to C3 as so on and on.

I'm pretty new to VBA.

Thanks !

Comment: You have already copied N3. Did you mean N4 to A3, N5 to D3 etc?

Comment: Yes I meant N4 and then there is more data below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Public Sub testing()
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenpUpdating  = False
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row Step 3
            .Cells(i + 1, "A") = .Cells(i, "N")
            .Cells(i + 1, "D") = .Cells(i + 1, "N")
            .Cells(i + 1, "C") = .Cells(i + 2, "N")
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenpUpdating  = True
End Sub
```

Transforms column N to the left as shown:

[image: DATA]

You can delete or hide empty column A rows with

```
.Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row, "A")).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Delete
```

or

```
.Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row, "A")).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate empty rows in new data ?

Comment: You mean to compress so in the above for example you would have a next d next g next to j and delete rows 3,4,6,7,9,10,11?

Comment: .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row, "A")).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Delete or .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row, "A")).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden  = True before the End WIth.